# how to select whole row in ant-design-vue table?

Tags: vue.js, antd

i have an ant-design-vue table which has the function to select the row and open a new drawer with the record.

this is the template of the table.

```
<a-table
    :dataSource="employeeData"
    :rowKey="record => record.sgid"
    :pagination="{ pageSize: size }"
    :columns="columns"
    :loading="loading"
    :scroll="{ x: 1300, y: 400 }"
    :rowSelection="{selectedRowKeys: selectedRowKeys, onChange: onSelectChange}"
  >
    <template slot="name" slot-scope="text, record">
      <div class="click-event" @click="select(record)">{{ text }}</div>
    </template>
    <template slot="id" slot-scope="text, record">
      <div class="click-event" @click="select(record)">{{ text }}</div>
    </template>
    <template slot="mobile" slot-scope="text, record">
      <div class="click-event" @click="select(record)">{{ text }}</div>
    </template>
</a-table>
```

with this code i add a `<div>` to all slot so that user can click anywhere in every column. but there is still some empty space between two column in a row that cannot be click. what should i do to make the user can click on a row to run the select function?

Comment: Could you add a online demo please? It might help us to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Wrap your column around a **Link** for redirection instead of an HTML anchor tag `<a> <slots /> </a>`.

---

- #### react-router-dom

You could use Link from `react-router-dom` and use it to trigger your component or container. This will also isolate your slot function logic in a separate component or container

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

 <Link to={`/redirect/to/slot-function-component/`}>
  <Row Content />
 </Link>

...
```

It is important to register this component in a `routes.js`

---

- #### Ant Design: Anchor Component

If you're going to stick with *Ant Design*, then you might wanna explore [**Anchor Component** **API**](https://ant.design/components/anchor/#API). Anchor Props and Link Props provides you with lots of options to implement your use case in multiple ways.

Explore the API and see what suits your requirements.